# Android App Store data

Tags: java, android

I have an android app which stores a bit of String data in an Object. I want to use this object all over the app.

Meaning: In my MainActivity i start a new intend getDataActivity, in this activity i get the data via TextFields and store them in a new Object file. after putting the data in i return via intent back to the MainActivity. In the main Activity I want to start a second Activity writeDataActivity. For that i need the data object from the getDataActivity.

Whats the best way to the data. It dont have to be a file or anything i can be temporally while the app is opened. I read something aber ContextData but Im not sure how to implement that. So whats the best way to save the data.

Data:

```
String url;
String username;
String password;
boolean connected;
```

Thx for any help or ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a singleton (e.g. a Credentials object which you create) to store the data. Alternatively you could just declare the Strings as `static` which will allow you to access those Strings anywhere. The data will be wiped when your process is killed/terminated by Android (leaving the app and coming back most of the time will not kill your app).

```
public class Credentials {
    public static String username;
    public static String password;
}
// write (assuming 'uname' is the user's name you want to save)
Credentials.username = uname;
// read
String user = Credentials.username;
```

If you wish to store the data *persistently* then you should use `SharedPreferences`. You can obtain this from any valid `Context` (e.g. your `Activity`).

```
// write (assuming 'uname' is the string you want to save)
// NOTE: getSharedPreferences needs a valid context (so you can call this in onResume/onPause, or just MyActivity.this.getSharedPreferences()
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("SharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("username", uname);

// read
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String username = settings.getString("username","");
```

Comment: thx I did it with SharedPreferences works fine. but you say the data is stored persistently, then where is it stored. physically I mean, xml file, object ?!

Comment: It is indeed stored as an XML file on your private data area. (/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml) - If you're storing sensitive data, consider encrypting it first and base64 encoding it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate class with the reference of your object. Each time you need it you call this class

Answer (score 0):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

It's pretty easy to save a string: (For example username)

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("username", yourUsername);
editor.commit();
```

To read this string use:

```
prefs.getString("username", "");
```